# How to find entries matching a month present in an intersection of intervals in SQLAlchemy or SQL?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

One of my users wants to answer the question:

"What are the requests that existed during any month of march between 2005 and 2010 ?"

The DB table "request" has 2 columns, `start_date` and `end_date`, representing the interval of the request life time.

The SQLAlchemy model look like this:

```
class Request(SomeBaseModel):
    ...
    start_date = db.Column(db.Date, default=date.today)
    end_date = db.Column(db.Date, default=in_one_year)
```

Then I have a process getting a span of 5 years and a month dynamically in Python:

```
`initial_date`, five_years_later, month_number = getTimePeriod()
```

From those parameters I have to list all the requests that started or ended between `initial_date` and `five_years_later`. This I can do quite easily by comparing `start_date` and `end_date` with `initial_date` and `five_years_later`.

However the hard part is to get only the requests that were existing during this particular month, while that month is also part of the (`initial_date`, `five_years_later`) interval. The rules are:

- The request can have existed before and after this month, but the month must be in its life time.
- The month can appear several times in the request life time, but cannot appear 0 time.
- The exact same month must appear in one request life time and in the (`initial_date`, `five_years_later`) interval.

I can do that by generating the start date and end date of each month for each years of the (`initial_date`, `five_years_later`) interval and then check if any of those pairs overlaps somewhere with the request life time:

```
        filters = []
        for year in range(initial_date, five_years_later + 1):
            month_start_date = datetime(year, month, 1)
            month_end_date = datetime(year, month, calendar.mdays[month])
            filters.append(
                (requeest.start_date <= month_end_date) &
                (request.end_date >= month_start_date)
            )
        is_active = functools.reduce(operator.or_, filters)
        auth_requests = auth_requests.filter(is_active)
```

However my guts tells me there is a better way.

An SQLAlchemy query would be the best possible answer, but an SQL version for Postgres would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I have broken down the problem.

Either
 - The duration of request should be greater than equal to 1 year.

Or
 - start_date must be during or after March **and** end_date should be during or before March.

AND

either of start_date/end_date must be in range (2005,2010)

This postgres query will check for conditions:

```
select * from request
where 1 = 
CASE
    WHEN extract(year from age(end_date,start_date)) >= 1 THEN 1
    WHEN (extract(month from start_date)::integer <= 3 
             AND extract(month from end_date)::integer >= 3 )
         AND extract(year from age(end_date,start_date)) < 1 THEN 1
    WHEN (extract(month from start_date)::integer >= 3 
             AND extract(month from end_date)::integer <= 3 )
         AND extract(year from age(end_date,start_date)) < 1 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END
AND ((extract(year from start_date)::integer >= 2005
and  extract(year from start_date)::integer <= 2010)
OR (extract(year from end_date)::integer >= 2005
and  extract(year from end_date)::integer <= 2010))
;
```

Edit: This is more complicated than I first realised. Edited the query to satisfy all conditions.

Comment: That seems much more complicated than my own solution.

Answer (score 1):

In effect your proposal in the question constructs a set of filters that evaluates the intersection between the start and end dates and the month in question.  So, you turn the month, start and end dates into around five filters (depending on boundary conditions) and then use the or operator.
Assuming that your columns are properly indexed (or that a full table scan is the right answer for your data if they are not), I don't think anything will perform better than that.  Your query gives Postgres a set of intervals to compare against.  Each row needs to be processed at most once.
For this problem that's ideal.
So my answer is that you have already found a best approach.  There may be other approaches that have the same performance characteristics, but what you have is easy to understand and performs well.

Comment: It feels good to believe so at least. So far, the query performed fine, although I don't know much about indexes and wonder what exactly I should index on this. The dates I guess ?